# Does there exist an identity element in $\mathbb R^3$ with the vector cross product?

Tags: vector-analysis

Consider $\mathbb R^3$ with the vector cross product. Does this structure have an identity element? Why or why not?

Comment: Please give me answer past.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. Can you pleas rephrase it.

Comment: Think about it geometrically. What is the geometric relationship between two vectors and their cross product? Remember that an identity element means that the original vector stays unchanged.

Comment: I rewrote your question to make it more clear, I hope you don't mind

Answer (score 5):

No, such an element does not exist. Suppose toward a contradiction that $e$ is the identity element. Then $e \times v = v$ for all $v$. Plugging in $v = e$, we get that $e \times e = e$, but we have that $e \times e = 0$ by definition of the cross product, so $e = 0$. But this is absurd since $0 \times v = 0$ for all $v$, and not all vectors are the zero vector.